# HQL using hibernatetemplate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I was trying to add subquery to existing query and run using hibernate template.

```
String query = "from Dispatch where ID='1011' and createdDt > sysdate - (coalesce((select timeout/60 from AppDetails where appId='1071'),10)/1440)";

List<Dispatch> dipatchhibernateTemplate.find(query);
```

then we are getting the error as "**right-hand operand of a binary operator was null**".

I have tried to search around but could not find any right results.

If someone can help how I can convert using hibernate **Criteria** is also fine.

Can some one please help.